# Can llvm-archer support g++ Tsan to understand Openmp? and How to do it?

Tags: g++, clang, openmp, llvm, thread-sanitizer

According to [Can I use Thread Sanitizer for OpenMP programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004809/can-i-use-thread-sanitizer-for-openmp-programs?rq=2), I konw Tsan doesn't support well for Openmp and I have resolved this issue according to the official documentation https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/openmp/tools/archer by using llvm-archer. But there is a question: I only can use clang++ to solve false positive, but g++ can't.
**min_example_code**:

**parallel.h**

```
#include "omp.h"
#include <vector>
namespace nio {
namespace parallel {

#define NUM_THREADS 3

template<typename ITER, typename FN>
void foreach(ITER beg, ITER end, FN fn) {
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(NUM_THREADS)
    for (auto i = beg; i != end; ++i) {
        fn(*i);
    }
}

template <typename FN>
void foreach(int n, FN fn) {
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(NUM_THREADS)
    for (auto i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        fn(i);
    }
}

} // namespace parallel
} // namespace nio
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "parallel.h"
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

const int N = 1e8;

int main(){
    std::vector<int> pre_numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    std::vector<int> curr_numbers;
    auto Square = [&](size_t i) {
        auto &input = pre_numbers[i];
        input *= input;
    };

    auto Zero = [&](size_t i) {
        auto &input = curr_numbers[i];
        input = 0;
    };

    auto Print = [&](size_t i) {
        auto &input = curr_numbers[i];
        std::cout << input << " ";
    };

    {
        nio::parallel::foreach (pre_numbers.size(), Square);
    }

    {
        for(const auto& input : pre_numbers) {
            curr_numbers.emplace_back(input);
        }
    }
    
    {
        nio::parallel::foreach (curr_numbers.size(), Zero);
    }
    
    {
        nio::parallel::foreach (curr_numbers.size(), Print);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

environment set:

```
sudo ln -s  /usr/local/llvm/lib/libomp.so /usr/lib/libomp.so
export OMP_TOOL_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/llvm/lib/libarcher.so
export TSAN_OPTIONS='ignore_noninstrumented_modules=1'
```

clang++ command:

```
clang++ main.cpp -fopenmp -fsanitize=thread -g
./a.out
```

g++ command:

```
g++ main.cpp -fopenmp -fsanitize=thread -g
export LD_PRELOAD=$LD_PRELOAD:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtsan.so.0
./a.out
```

I am sure clang++ can support Tsan to understand Openmp, but g++ can't. And I must use g++ to compile my code, it's so sad:-( If you have some good solutions, please tell me. Have a good day, eveyone:D